# Invalid signature when requesting AWS with colon (:) in the URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, httprequest, signature

I am making a request to AWS: `POST https://myapi.com/users/us-west-2:123`

It works fine if I drop the `us-west-2:` but including that generates

```
The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.
```

It seems the cause of this is the `:` because it needs to be URL encoded. Generating the signature with the encoded uri generates the same error!

```
POST https://myapi.com/users/us-west-2%3A123
```

What is happening? My signature generator uses

```
{
  "path": "/users/us-west-2%3A123",
  "headers": {
    "X-Amz-Date": timestamp,
    "host": "myapi.com",
  },
  "body": "",
}
```

I use this generated to make a `POST` request to `https://myapi.com/users/us-west-2%3A123` with no body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow. I got it.

Here's what's happening:

I am generating am requesting `/users/us-west-2%3A123` and when I generate the signature the package I was using (`react-native-aws-signature`) encoded the % as a percent so it turned the `%` into `%25`!

The fix was to switch to `aws4` or rather the fork `aws4-react-native` and use the `doNotEncodePath: true` option in the signing request. I am also making the `fetch` request (node) to `/users/us-west-2:123`.

I'd like to thank Amazon Support, GitHub, and luck.

Answer (score 0):

Im also stuck with this problem. In our application we want to be able to send the id as a pathParamter like this

```
/admin/eu-west-1:xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx
error Msg: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method.
```

If i remove the colon (:) and replace it with any any other character like `%` or any number/char my request goes trough.

I know there is possible solutions to refactor the API to take in 2 seperate parameters like region and id.

```
/users/{region}/{id}
Example: /users/eu-west-1/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxx
```

But wince we want to follow a strict pattern for our API this is not the best solution for us.

Our Pattern:

```
/someObject
GET - get a list
POST - Create
PUT - Update ALL
/{id}
    GET - Get one
    PUT - Update one
    Delete - Delete one
```

Comment: Make sure the way you're generating the signature encodes the `:` as `%3A`. Make a request to the path with the `%3A` with the signature using the `%3A`. My issue was I was encoding the `%` twice.